# Combining multiple awk output statements into one line

Tags: bash, awk

I have some ascii files I’m processing, with 35 columns each, and variable number of rows. I need to take the difference between two columns (N+1), and place the results into a duplicate ascii file on column number 36. Then, I need to take another column, and divide it (row by row) by column 36, and place that result into the same duplicate ascii file in column 37.

I’ve done similar processing in the past, but by outputting temp files for each awk command, reading each successive temp file in to eventually create a final ascii file. Then, I would delete the temp files after. I’m hoping there is an easier/faster method than having to create a bunch of temp files.

Below is an initial working processing step, that the above awk commands would need to follow and fit into. This step gets the data from foo.txt, removes the header, and processes only the rows containing a particular, but varying, string.

```
cat foo.txt | tail -n +2 | awk '$17 ~ /^[F][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/' >> foo_new.txt
```

There’s another processing step for different data files, that I would also need the 2 new columns discussed earlier. This is simply appending a unique file name from what’s being catted to the last column of every row in a new ascii file. This command is actually in a loop with varying input files, but I’ve simplified it here.

```
cat foo.txt | tail -n +2 | awk -v fname="$fname" '{print $0 OFS fname;}' >> foo_new.txt
```

An example of one of the foo.txt files.

```
 20 0  5  F001
  4 2  3  F002
 12 4  8  F003
100 10 29 O001
```

Below would be the example foo_new.txt desired. The requested 2 columns of output from awk (last 2 columns). In this example, column 5 is the difference between column 3 and 2 plus 1. Column 6 is the result of column 1 divided by column 5.

```
 20 0  5  F001 6  3.3
  4 2  3  F002 2  2.0
 12 4  8  F003 5  2.4
```

For the second example foo_new.txt. The last column is an example of fname. These are computed in the shell script, and passed to awk. I don't care if the results in column 7 (fname) are at the end or placed between columns 4 and 5, so long as it gets along with the other awk statements.

```
 20 0  5  F001 6  3.3 C1
  4 2  3  F002 2  2.0 C2
 12 4  8  F003 5  2.4 C3
```

The best luck so far, but unfortunately this is producing a file with the original output first, and the added output below it. I'd like to have the added output appended on as columns (#5 and #6).

```
cat foo.txt | tail -n +2 | awk '$17 ~ /^[F][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/' >> foo_new.txt
cat foo_new.txt | awk '{print $4=$3-$2+1, $5=$1/($3-$2+1)}' >> foo_new.txt
```

Comment: I suggest to replace both `“` with `"`.

Comment: Please do add samples of input and expected output in your post in CODE TAGS and let us know then.

Comment: You need to clarify this, but nothing you are describing seems to require **any** temp files. `awk` can compute `d=$r1-$r2`, `q=$r3/d`, and then `print $0, d, q` for each row.

Comment: I've added an example at the bottom and cleaned some writing up @RavinderSingh13 and Jeff.

Comment: Trying to follow your comment Jeff, this does not work:


    cat foo.txt | tail -n +2 | awk -v d=$2-$1+1 -v r=$d/$1 '$17 ~ /^[F][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/' '{print $0 $d $r}' >> foo_new.txt

Comment: you have to do the assignments inside of the awk code block, not pass them in as arguments. i.e. `awk '{d=$2-$1+1 ; r=$d/$1; ...; print ... }' file`. Read about awk `NR` variable at [Awk Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) it may reduce your code. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thanks for the tip, but I'm still having no luck with assigning them inside the code block. It doesn't want to write anything at all. The filter code assignment is throwing it off. The best luck I've had so far, I'll add shortly to above.

Comment: `processes only the rows containing a particular, but varying, string` ? Why? What for? Why do you match `$17` with `/^[F][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/`? What is the input file `foo.txt` ? Please post excerpt from the input file matching the output you except? Why do you match? `is the difference between column 3 and 2 (N+1).` - difference between `0` and `5` is `5`, not `6`.

Comment: That looks like you want `$3 - $2 + 1` but I am not sure. Your post is very unclear. Please post example input file with 3 columns. Then post example output file with 5 columns matching the input file. What is that `N+1` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk The input file (foo.txt) contains a lot of data, and contains data that needs to be sorted (identified in column 17) and output into different files.

I've tried to simplify the contents of the file, so I could get an example of what to do, then I can apply it to the larger files. I'll edit the topic to include an example of both input and output.

Your reply below looks correct (I will try it later), but unfortunately the data will still need to be sorted. So I would need to create a temp file, apply the code you supplied below, output to a new file, then delete the temp file.

Comment: The main question is how to put the three awk arguments together for both cat examples above, without having to make and delete temp files, and while preserving the original data files. The reply below may help with combining two awk commands (the difference and division quantities), but it doesn’t combine it with the sorting awk command. So, I’m still stuck with creating and deleting unnecessary files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an input file `data` with header line like this (based closely on your minimal example):

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
 20 0  5  F001
  4 2  3  F002
 12 4  8  F003
100 10 29 O001
```

You want the output to contain a column 5 that is the value of `$3 - $2 + 1` (column 3 minus column 2 plus 1), and a column 6 that is the value of column 1 divided by column 5 (with 1 decimal place in the output), and a file name that is based on a variable `fname` passed to the script but that has a unique value for each line.  And you only want lines where column 4 matches F and 3 digits, and you want to skip the first line.  That can all be written directly in `awk`:

```
awk -v fname=C '
NR == 1                     { next }
$4 ~ /^F[0-9][0-9][0-9]$/   { c5 = $3 - $2 + 1
                              c6 = sprintf("%.1f", $1 / c5)
                              print $0, c5, c6, fname NR
                            }' data
```

You could write that on one line too:

```
awk -v fname=C 'NR==1{next} $4~/^F[0-9][0-9][0-9]$/ { c5=$3-$2+1; print $0,c5,sprintf("%.1f",$1/c5), fname NR }' data
```

The output is:

```
 20 0  5  F001 6 3.3 C2
  4 2  3  F002 2 2.0 C3
 12 4  8  F003 5 2.4 C4
```

Clearly, you could change the file name so that the counter starts from 0 or 1 by using `counter++` or `++counter` respectively in place of the `NR` in the `print` statement, and you could format it with leading zeros or whatever else you want with `sprintf()` again.  If you want to drop the first line of each file, rather than just the first file, change the `NR == 1` condition to `FNR == 1` instead.

Note that this does not need the preprocessing provided by `cat foo.txt | tail -n +2`.

Comment: Thank you. With a few tweaks to suit my data, this answer worked for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to take the difference between two columns (N+1), and place the results into a duplicate ascii file on column number 36. Then, I need to take another column, and divide it (row by row) by column 36, and place that result into the same duplicate ascii file in column 37.

That's just:

```
awk -vN=9 -vanother_column=10 '{ v36 = $N - $(N+1); print $0, v36, $another_column / v36 }' input_file.tsv
```

I guess your file has some "header"/special "first line", so if it's the first line,  then preserve it:

```
awk ... 'NR==1{print $0, "36_header", "37_header"} NR>1{ ... the script above ... }`
```

Taking first 3 columns from the example script you presented, and substituting `N` for `2` and `another_column` for `1`, we get the following script:

```
# recreate input file
cat <<EOF |
20 0  5
4 2  3
12 4  8
100 10 29
EOF
tr -s ' ' | 
tr ' ' '\t'  > input_file.tsv


awk -vOFS=$'\t' -vIFS=$'\t' -vN=2 -vanother_column=1 '{ tmp = $(N + 1) - $N; print $0, tmp, $another_column / tmp }' input_file.tsv
```

and it will output:

```
20  0   5   5   4
4   2   3   1   4
12  4   8   4   3
100 10  29  19  5.26316
```

Such script:

```
awk -vOFS=$'\t' -vIFS=$'\t' -vN=2 -vanother_column=1 '{ tmp = $(N + 1) - $N + 1; print $0, tmp, sprintf("%.1f", $another_column / tmp) }' input_file.tsv
```

I think get's closer output to what you want:

```
20  0   5   6   3.3
4   2   3   2   2.0
12  4   8   5   2.4
100 10  29  20  5.0
```

And I guess that by that `(N+1)` you meant "the difference between two columns with 1 added".